# Is it better to expose the LiveData object as a parameter of the ViewModel or rather returned by a member function call?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

> Usually MutableLiveData is used in the ViewModel and then the ViewModel only exposes immutable LiveData objects to the observers.
>   https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#update_livedata_objects

Is it better to expose the LiveData object as a parameter of the ViewModel object:

```
val data: LiveData<String>
    get() = _data
```

or rather return it with a call to a member function:

```
fun getData(): LiveData<String> {
    return _data
}
```

So in the first case I could write

```
println(viewModel.data)
```

while in the latter

```
println(viewModel.getData())
```

Comment: Either can be done but the first would be more kotlin like vs the other being java like

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, both are basically the same. But as @tyczj says, the first form is more idiomatic. So, I would prefer first one.